# Get length of mp3 file

Tags: php, audio, mp3

Users upload mp3 files and I need to get their length. What is the least-effort way to do this in PHP? By least effort I mean whatever way requires the least amount of code and with as little non-native PHP functions as possible.

I tried implementing the code suggested in the answer below:

```
<?PHP
$f = 'numbers/4.mp3';
$m = new mp3file($f);
$a = $m->get_metadata();

if ($a['Encoding']=='Unknown')
    echo "?";
else if ($a['Encoding']=='VBR')
    print_r($a);
else if ($a['Encoding']=='CBR')
    print_r($a);
unset($a);
?>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mp3file' not found in /home/a1865444/public_html/save-audio.php on line 3
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: you mean play length? because `filesize()` gets you the byte-length. If they're VBR mp3's, then the ONLY way to calculate the playtime is to scan the ENTIRE file and count how many mp3 frames are present.

Comment: Yes, i mean play length. how do i count the frames?

Comment: Save the class code you see on that page in a `mp3file.php` and `include 'mp3file.php'` before your code. **Seriously?!** This is what you get when someone with not clue about PHP jumps at the deep end without any basic knowledge. Read a PHP book first. It's made of pages and teach you stuff. If you can't tell why that errors appears, you need a book.

Comment: scan the file and detect frame. they have a specific bit pattern. assuming the file's PURE mp3 data and not mp3-in-mpeg-video or whatever, once you've found the first frame, finding the rest is just a matter of figuring out frame size and jumping forward that many bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this getduration function: http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3

Comment: updated question with my attempt to implement your suggested code

Comment: You must download and then include the `mp3file.class.php`. Read my suggested page to end pls :P

Comment: Hey did it work for you? I tried that mp3file.class.php thing and somehow the duration am getting is not accurate. Now I think I should just count the frames and multiply them with 0.026 secs

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my lots of time.